# does the determinant of a square matrix over field/commutative ring have the same Leibniz formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, determinant, finite-fields

This might be a stupid question but nevertheless I want to be sure.

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix such that
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} &  a_{1,2} & \dots & a_{1,n} \\
a_{2,1} &  a_{2,2} & \dots & a_{2,n} \\
\vdots &  \vdots & \ddots &  \vdots \\
a_{n,1} &  a_{n,2} & \dots & a_{n,n} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Is it true that 
\begin{equation}
\det(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,\sigma_i}
\end{equation}
even if the elements of A are from a finite field (or a commutative ring)?
Also, does the regular way of calculating the determinant of a matrix with elements $a_{i,j} \in \mathbb{R}$ (using determinant of minors) carry over to the case where $a_{i,j} \in \mathbb{F}$, a finite field or if $a_{i,j} \in R$, a commutative ring?

By "regular way" I mean picking a row or a column and then iterating through it element by element (from $i = 1$ to $n$), finding the determinant of the minor result from eliminating the row and column of that element then multiplying it by $(−1)^i \times$ the value of that (row/column) element, then sum over all results of this iteration.

Finally, I would really appreciate  it if someone can provide a reference (book or lecture notes) on the subject.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the "regular way"? And yes, the formula is the same for any commutative ring. I prove lots of basic results using the "sum over permutations" formula in Chapter 6 of [*Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/primes2015/sols.pdf); at the beginning of that chapter I also give references to various books.

Comment: By "regular way" I mean picking a row or a column and then iterating through it element by element (from i = 1 to n), finding the determinant of the minor result from eliminating the row and column of that element then multiplying it by $(-1)^i \times$ the value of that (row\column) element, then sum over all results of this iteration.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and the reference you provided..  looks like exactly what I'm looking for!!

Comment: Indeed, the formulas for evaluating a determinant are $\Bbb Z$-formulas, so they are universal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, not only does it work but some authors use it to prove Nakayama's Lemma.  It can also be used to prove the commutative ring version of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.  See for example the early pages of Matsumura or of Atiyah-MacDonald.